# where can I download the latest System.Windows.Forms.dll?

Tags: c#

`System.Windows.Forms.dll` is located in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`.

I want to download the latest `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to replace the old one on my machine.

Does anyone know where can I download it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're looking for .NET Framework 4 you can download it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx.

You can't replace System.Windows.Forms in the 2.0 directory with the 4.0 assembly.  When you install the 4.0 framework it will create a new framework install location along side the 2.0 location (c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319).

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: For .NET 5 it's in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll`